# How to Count XSL Nodes?

Tags: html, xslt, report, qtp

i have a nodes generated after automation run from XSL file 
i need to count (TestCases - Passed and Failed) in suite node as a structured that appear in below image

[image]

this link have the xsl file 
https://sites.google.com/site/feras13545646/Report.xsl?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: Please show a simplified sample of your input xml and what you expect as an output. Also what version of XSLT are you using? I presume you mean XML element nodes. There is no such thing as XSL nodes.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/feras13545646/Report.xsl?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: You linked the stylesheet, but forgot to supply the sample input XML. This is not the best way to ask a question on SO. For better results, you should list (not link) a simplified version of your input document, rules of transformation, your expected output (by listing, not graphic), and what you have tried so far (a simplified version of the stylesheet). If you post or link to a huge stylesheet that contains a lot of specific details not really relevant to the nub of your question, it is going to put a lot of potential helpers off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a COUNT function within your xsl file which will count the number of nodes that contain a particular value, in this case count how many times "PASS" or "FAIL" appear.

Example snippet below:

```
<table border='0' width='100%'>
    <tr><td><b>Total Tests Passed:</b></td><td><xsl:value-of select="count(path/to/testresult[value = 'PASS'])"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Total Tests Failed:</b></td><td><xsl:value-of select="count(path/to/testresult[value = 'FAIL'])"/></td></tr>             
</table>
```

The main node in here is below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(path/to/testresult[value = 'PASS'])"/>
```

This is where you specify what value will be returned by counting all nodes in the path "path/to/testresult" which have a value of PASS.